# Hide Button Index Page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm new in asp.net and I looked around for a question but couldn't find the answer. In my view index Company I tried to hide the button if my index is populate but I can't find the solution, this is a part of my code. If someone can help I would really appreciate it.

```
`<div class="container p-3">
    <div class="row pt-4">
        <div class="col-6">
            <h2 class="text-primary">Company List</h2>
        </div>

        //HERE NOT WORKING
        <div class="col-6 text-end">
            @If(Model.Count != null)
            {
                //do nothing
            }
            else
            {
                <a asp-controller="Company" asp-action="Create" class="btn btn-primary">
                <i class="bi bi-plus-circle"></i> &nbsp; Create New Company
            </a>
            }
        </div>
    </div>`
```

Answer (score 3):

`Model.Count` won't be null,you will never get into it,For your requirement ,it should be `Model.Count() != 0`

Comment: Thank you, but I change to !=0 and give a error : Operator "!=" cannot be applied to operands of type method group and int.

Comment: Try `Model.Count() != 0`.

Comment: How did you specific the type of the viewmodel with @model ?

Comment: Guys working in this way. @if(Model.Count() == 0). Thank you to help guys.